# how to apply texture to grid of squares using OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to learn OpenGL, and it's a bit daunting. To get started I am trying to use it to create some effects on a 2D image. Basically, I want to take an image (say 1000px by 1000px) and divide it into a grid of equally sized squares (say a 10 by 10 grid) and then manipulate the squares individually (like turn one square black, flip another over, make another "fall" off the screen, etc). I've followed some basic online instructions (http://blog.jayway.com/2010/12/30/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-vi-textures/) on how to map a texture to a simple square, but I'm having problems with mapping the texture to a more complex arrangement of multiple squares.

1) Given a 2x2 (and larger size) grid of squares, how can I map a single texture/image over the entire grid? That is, what are the texture coordinates that OpenGL expects (and in what order) to make this work? I can't seem to wrap my head around how to figure out the order of the "UV" coordinates on a larger polygon structure.

2) Since I will ultimately be transforming, rotating, etc. each individual square of the grid, would it be better to create each square of the grid and individually divide the texture/bitmap and apply each piece of the image to each square separately? If so, do you have any recommendations on how to do efficiently divide the bitmap into pieces?

Any and all help, links, suggestions, etc. will be greatly appreciated. I'm doing this in an Android app with assumed support for OpenGL ES 2, but I assume most of the OpenGL discussion/concepts are platform agnostic. I don't want to include some large framework or toolkit to do this if possible since I want a lot of speed and minimum size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the more important reply, #2, you really don't want to do more texture switches than you absolutely need. They're an insane performance loss.

Back to #1, the way you do this is actually quite straight forward. Your texture resides in a *unit square* of coordinates (0,0) to (1,1). This is called texture-space coordinates, and the axes are called U and V respectively. So each go between 0 and 1 and cover your whole image.

Now when you create your objects, vertex by vertex (through a vertex buffer or immediately), you can send a second set of coordinates, the UV texture coordinates, for each vertex. You use this to "slice up" your image into parts.

The easiest way to do your specific application is to take the vertex coordinate, divide it by the length of length of the image and multiply it by the length of the small square you're building. This will obviously not work once you start rotating your squares, but maybe it will help you visualize the process better.

Note how this is completely platform independent, you can use the same reasoning for DirectX applications or whatever!

Answer (score 1):

1)I think the keyword you search for is "Texture atlas".

Some hints, but you may find better explanations on the Internet as im still learning too: (i use OpenGl 2.1, and GLSL 1.2 so ymmv)
The vertex shader has something like this:

```
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;  
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;  
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;  

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 vertTexCoord;

void main()
{ 
  vertTexCoord = texcoord;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

in your fragment shader you do something like this:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 vertTexCoord;

void main()
{
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vertTexCoord);
}
```

and then, for example, if you want a 2x2 grid of squares (texture divided in 4 parts) you would have vertices like this; (assuming the squares are 1 unit wide and tall)
(uv = texcoord, vertex = position)
[square1](http://k.min.us/ilEpv8.png)
and the next square to the **right** would look like this:
[square2](http://k.min.us/ilHZ9G.png)

It's kinda important to remember that while vertex coordinates can go over 1 and below 0, texture coordinates can not( always between 0 and 1).

2) I wouldn't divide the bitmap, since using texture atlases(plural?) is already quite fast, and i doubt you would gain a significant speed gain (if at all).

I hope i could help! (also sorry but i couldn't embed the images directly, please give me rep. so i can do in the future! :))